# facebook send button

Tags: facebook, button, send

I saw [facebook send button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) 
Is there any way to use that service with PHP SDK?

Comment: What do you mean "with PHP SDK"? as long as you are loading the FB JS library with xfbml support, you can use it. If you are using the xfbml like button, or the comments plugin...you can use it. Bottom lien, it has nothing to do with the PHP SDK!

Answer (score 0):

I think the example here (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/494) sums it up pretty well:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like href="example.com" show_faces="true" width="450" send="true">
</fb:like>
```

The PHP SDK doesn't offer any help for the send button. All you need is the JavaScript SDK. Insert the code above into one of your pages and replace `example.com` with your resource to send and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the other answer is for a combined "send and like" button ..

Here is for only send :

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOURAPPID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:send href="example.com" font="arial"></fb:send>
```